# Whether there should be a difference to copy files in parallel and not in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, task-parallel-library, multiprocessing

I tried to copy 200 files with both below solutions but I didn't saw the difference ( I used `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to measure time). In both cases it took 8 seconds. Should not the second(Parallel) solution be faster? I thought because it is IO operations using Parallel will speed up the copy.

What I'm missing?

```
// Case1 - Regular iteration
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
    file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
}

// Case2 - Parallel
Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
    file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
});
```

Comment: Actually parallelizing disk IO goes with a good chance to **slow things down**. When copying two files at the same time the disk needs to read from both files, i.e. from totally different locations. When copying them one after another you can read each file completely - without the disk having to read lots of different areas.

Comment: Well, might be an interesting time to try this with a high-latency network drive.

Comment: ..and with a configurable number of threads in the pool used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parallel execution of tasks doesn't guarantee performance improvements.

In your case, file copying will likely be IO bound, not CPU bound. The CPU typically has much more bandwidth available than the IO device (unless you happen to be using a Fusion IO card or something), so IO actions tend to cause the CPU to wait a lot.

Tasks that use a lot of CPU can be done in parallel to get performance gains. Tasks that also wait on external factors can also benefit from being shifted onto another thread so as not to become a blocking task.

However, tasks that are waiting for the same external resource will likely see little benefit unless that external resource can itself handle the traffic associated with multiple threads (IO tends to never be able to handle the traffic and could in fact cause contention of the resource, slowing it down).

Comment: As above, I would like to see this tried with a network drive, or even two network drives.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as @Adam above, but with added points:

If you get a chance, you might like to try this with one, or two networked drives.  File transfer on high-latency connections have a large setup latency that may well give an advantage to the multithreaded solution, especially with large numbers of small files.

It may well be also useful to use a pool with a small, fixed number of threads, (2 say), to see if that reduces disk contention and improves performance.

If you like my answer, please upvote @Adam, not me.

Comment: Isn't the network drive the same as local drive. I mean eventually it's written to the same drive(the same resource) though it's network drive. Am I right?